# Java - RSA публичный и приватный ключ в виде String

Tags: java, rsa

Требуется шифровать пароли на клиентской стороне (Java апплет). Пароль нужно зашифровать приватным ключом, а публичный нужно отправить в базу данных, что бы потом достать его и расшифровать. 
Пара ключей генерируется следующим образом:

```
  KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");  
           keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
           KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();  
           PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();  
           PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
```

И с такими ключами шифрование и обратное действие происходят без проблем, но чтобы хранить ключ в БД, методом toString() он преобразуется в строку. А как эту же строку сделать типом PublicKey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28294968/5506820). Допускаю, что blob твоего ключа хранится в base64.

```
byte[] publicBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(publicK);
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я видел это же решение, но Eclipse ругался, оказывается класс Base64 нужно было импортить из commons-codec-1.10, а не из стандартного .util пакета

Comment: @user2858470 в java 8 есть [встроенное решение для base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html), но с немного другим интерфейсом